# Connection timeout while connecting jupyter enterprise gateway from jupyterhub

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

i am using Jupyterhub 3.2.1 jupyter enterprise gateway 3.2.1 on k8s 1.25 while connecting to JEG to list and spwan remote kernel i am getting below error.

```
Z [I 2024-01-10 13:17:31.189 ServerApp] 200 GET /user/jovyan/api/terminals?1704892657311 (jovyan@127.0.0.1) 0.72ms
```

2024-01-10T13:18:22.192528667Z [I 2024-01-10 13:18:22.192 ServerApp] 200 GET /user/jovyan/api/me?1704892708321 (jovyan@127.0.0.1) 0.94ms
2024-01-10T13:18:22.764841954Z [I 2024-01-10 13:18:22.764 ServerApp] 101 GET /user/jovyan/api/events/subscribe?token=[secret] (jovyan@127.0.0.1) 0.97ms
2024-01-10T13:19:29.995576942Z [E 2024-01-10 13:19:29.995 ServerApp] Bad message (TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting')): {'name': 'ServerApp', 'msg': 'Exception while trying to launch kernel via Gateway URL http://enterprise-gateway.enterprise-gateway.svc.cluster.local:8888 , [Errno 110] Connection timed out', 'args': (TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'),), 'levelname': 'ERROR', 'levelno': 40, 'pathname': '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/gateway/gateway_client.py', 'filename': 'gateway_client.py', 'module': 'gateway_client', 'exc_info': None, 'exc_text': None, 'stack_info': None, 'lineno': 812, 'funcName': 'gateway_request', 'created': 1704892769.9951384, 'msecs': 995.0, 'relativeCreated': 148853.8899421692, 'thread': 140580579428160, 'threadName': 'MainThread', 'processName': 'MainProcess', 'process': 7}
2024-01-10T13:19:29.998097118Z [E 2024-01-10 13:19:29.995 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /user/jovyan/api/kernels?1704892645918 (127.0.0.1)
2024-01-10T13:19:29.998121127Z     HTTPServerRequest(protocol='https', host='jupyter.xyz.com', method='GET', uri='/user/jovyan/api/kernels?1704892645918', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
2024-01-10T13:19:29.998125801Z     Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-01-10T13:19:29.998128775Z       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1786, in _execute
2024-01-10T13:19:29.998139181Z         result = await result
2024-01-10T13:19:29.998142001Z                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^[image]

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed with below network rule change in jupyterhub 3.2.1 helm config under singleuser

```
  networkPolicy:
    enabled: false
```